# Ussing enum in processing switch case statment

Tags: enums, processing

I am trying to use "enum" in processing, in order to use it inside an "switch case" statment.

I am working on Processing 3.3.6. 
I placed the "enum" statment in a new tab, names "Status.java".
I declared on the enum iteslf in the main tab.
I cant inicialize the enum that was creted with a value.

here is my code:

"Satus.java" tab:

```
enum State {A,B,C};
```

"Main" tab:

```
State state1=A;

void setup()
{

}

void draw()
{  
  println(state1);  
  switch (state1)
  {
      case A:
        println("A");
      case B:
        println("B");
      case C:
        println("C");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to tell the *status* tab that it is a class:

```
static class status {
   enum State {A,B,C};
}
```

In processing you'll need to use **static class** token, rather than **public class**, as you would in Java.

---

At the moment, the *main* class does not know what a *State* object is. This is why Processing cannot resolve / initialise your variable *state1*.

Tell it to look for the type in the *status* class like so:

```
Status.State state1 = Status.State.A;
```

---

Finally, don't forget to add *break;* after each case in the switch statement otherwise a match for A will also print B and C (switch statements fall through).

```
    switch (state1) {
        case A :
            println("A");
            break;
        case B :
            println("B");
            break;
        case C :
            println("C");
            break;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to explicitly access State.A when assigning the variable.
E.g.

```
State state1=State.A;
```

instead of

```
State state1=A;
```

and remember to use the [break](https://processing.org/reference/break.html) statement, otherwise you'll hit all cased.
Here's a basic version of you code above in a single sketch file:

```
enum State {A,B,C};

State state1=State.A;

void setup()
{

}

void draw()
{  
  println("state1",state1);
  switch (state1)
  {
      case A:
        println("A");
        break;
      case B:
        println("B");
        break;
      case C:
        println("C");
        break;
      default:
        println("default: undefined state");
        break;
  }
}
```

Comment: Great ! Feel free to vote (arrow up) and/or check mark the answer if is the solution to your problem ;)